# Бутафор - настоящее слово или моя выдумка? | "Бутафор" - an actual word or my fantasy

Tags: словарь

Несколько недель назад я писал кое-что Вконтакте и с удивлением для себя обнаружил, что слово "бутафор" у меня подчеркивалось как содержащее ошибку.

Для меня это слово стояло в одном ряду с такими как "бондарь", "экзальтированный" и так далее, то есть действительно редко используемым, однако безусловно существующим. Факт, что это слово я обнаружил в единственном словаре (причем малоизвестном, ни Даля, ни Ожегова), изумил меня еще больше, и с того момента меня терзают сомнения, которые я хотел бы развеять.

Так существует или нет это слово?

Comment: English translation. Few weeks ago, I was writing some stuff in Vkontakte and with utter amazement realized that the word "бутафор" was marked as if it was misspelled. As to me, this word was in the same row with such words as "бондарь", "экзальтированный" et cetera, i.e. it is not definitely on the top of anyone's tongue, however this word in my opinion undoubtedly exists. The fact that I managed to find this word in only one dictionary, - which by the way I have never heard of; it was neither Ozhegov's nor Dal's dictionary - surprised me even more...

Comment: ... and ever since I'm heavily tortured by the uncertainty. So, does it exist it all?

Comment: Гугл это слово знает: [тыц](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80). Значение: *Театральный работник, ведающий бутафорией.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот [ссылка](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/fre_rus/81778/%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80) на список всех словарей, в которых оно зафиксировано. Насколько список достоверен, судить не берусь, но там есть и Даль, и Ожегов.

Сам я не уверен, что когда-либо с ним встречался, но, встретившись, проблемы с пониманием его смысла (который подтвердили соварные статьи) не испытал, и по уху (или по глазу) оно мне не резануло.

Comment: Любопытно, что у меня поисковик отказывается предоставлять релевантную информацию. Только романы, в которых оно есть. Использую Google.

Comment: я тоже Гугл, отыскалось по первому же запросу кириллицей, может у вас дело в настройках